# Does the Ancestral Guardian barbarian's Ancestral Protectors feature only work on your first attack after raging, or can you apply it every turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, rage

Does the Ancestral Protectors feature only work on your first attack after raging, or can you apply it every turn?

I have been wanting to make a Path of the Ancestral Guardian Barbarian, and I have been asking myself this question. Because if it does, it sounds pretty good, and maybe even on the overpowered side of things. Just imagine it against a boss.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Every turn

The [Path of the Ancestral Guardian barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheAncestralGuardian)'s [Ancestral Guardians](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#AncestralProtectors-636) feature says (XGtE, p. 10; emphasis mine):

> **While you’re raging**, the first creature you hit with an attack on your turn becomes the target of the warriors, which hinder its attacks.

This means that the benefit applies *whenever* you're raging: the first creature you hit on that turn is affected by the feature.

If the intent was to only apply on the turn you enter a rage, it would say so explicitly (e.g. "When you enter a rage, ...") - but it doesn't. The "first creature you hit with an attack on your turn" bit applies during every turn that you are in a rage at the time you make your first attack on that turn.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so quickly, you just confirmed what my next character was going to be.

Comment: @LucasLecours: Glad to help! If you found my answer helpful, you should click the check-mark icon to the left of it to accept it - though you might want to wait a day or so to allow other respondents to answer as well.

Comment: Beat me to it, and I fixed a typo.  Team win!  :)

Comment: I believe the word "Guardian" in the name is supposed to be a big flashing clue that this path is intended for tanking. Its only "OP" if you ignore the fact that you're giving up the opportunity to do more damage that is provided by all the other paths.